# How to handle onchange event on drop-downs that are dynamically generated by jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create drop-downs as per the int value specified in **txtCols** on its **onkeyup** function like this:

```
$("#txtCols").keyup(function(){ 
    var $count = $(this).val();

    $("#holder").html('');

    // define matrix header options available
    var matrixHeaders = {
        'TB': 'Text Box',
        'DD': 'Drop Down',
        'CL': 'Calendar'
    }

    for ($i=0;$i<$count;$i++) 
    { 

        var s = $('<select id="header'+$i+'"/>');
        for(var val in matrixHeaders) {
            $('<option />', {value: val, text: matrixHeaders[val]}).appendTo(s);
        }
        s.appendTo('#holder');
    } 

});
```

The drop-downs are generated with **id='header+i' [increment variable]**
Now, on the selection of these drop-downs, i want to trigger an event basically to generate Text Box, Drop Down or Calendar as per the selections made.

My code for it is this:

```
$(function(j) {
   $('#header' + j).change(function() {
      alert('Got Value');
   });
}(j));
```

Also tried:

```
$(document).on('change', '#header' + j, function() {        
  alert('hii');
}(j));
```

But this event is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

first add class to your selects smth like:   select id="header'+$i+'" class="header"/

next add handler:

```
$(".header").live("change", function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("id").split("header").join(""); //get i
    var opt = $("#header" + id + " option:selected").val(); //or whatever you need
    switch (opt) {
      case ..
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the on function to have the handler called on dynamically added elements :

```
$(document).on('change', '#header' + j, function() {
```

or, for any `j` :

```
$(document).on('change', '[id^="header"]', function() {
```

But I would rather use a class than a selector matching start of id :

```
$(document).on('change', '.header', function() {
...
var s = $('<select class=header id="header'+$i+'"/>');
```

Comment: please see... my code.. i have edited .. Is dat what you are saying ?? Its below.. **Also tried** header

Comment: I suggest pls.. give me full script.. as its not working.. in this way.